# How to get specific value from filename by substr-instr

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 file which names like
**abc_primary.log**
and **abc_secondary.log** and i need the output like primary and secondary only using substr and instr.

```
select SUBSTR(name1,(LENGTH(name1)-INSTR(REVERSE(name1), '.', 1)+2)) 
from 
(
  select 
    'abc_primary.log' as name1 ,
    'abc_secondary.log' as name2 
  from dual
);
```

here i can get the output is **'log'** which is the right-side part of the file. But i need the output will be only either **primary** or **secondary**. 
Can anyone here help me to get the value.
Thanks

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: What's wrong with using `regexp_replace()`?

Comment: i have not used regexp earlier, so might be that helps, but i am not aware of :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use only `substr` and `instr` then you could write it like here:

```
select substr(substr(name1, 1, instr(name1, '.') - 1), instr(name1, '_') + 1) n1, 
       substr(substr(name2, 1, instr(name2, '.') - 1), instr(name2, '_') + 1) n2 
  from (
    select 'abc_primary.log' as name1, 'abc_secondary.log' as name2 
    from dual);
```

Result:

```
N1      N2
------- ---------
primary secondary
```

Comment: just one quick doubt, if my filename is like "abc_def_xyz_primary.log" which means 3 underscore before primary word, how to take that????

Comment: Use `instr(name3, '_', 1, 3) + 1)` or `instr(name3, '_', -1) + 1)` as second `instr()`, like in this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=415615ef72d16621791608fce63d7e32).